# Node Express how to edit the app.post url

Tags: node.js, express, post

I have a simple example of Google App Script sending a post request to my Node application. This is working perfectly.

**GAS**

```
function send_webhook_test() {
  const url = 'http://my.ip.address/folder'   
  var body = {msg:'hello from gas'}

  var params = {
    'method': 'post',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload':JSON.stringify(body)
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);

  console.log(res)

}
```

**Node**

```
const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const app = express()
const PORT = 3000

const path = require('path');

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req)
  console.log(req.body)
  res.status(200).end()
})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))
```

I would like to change the `app.post` from `('/')` to `('someValue')`. So I make the following edit:

**GAS**

```
const url = 'http://my.ip.address/folder/someValue'
```

**Node**

```
app.post('/someValue', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req)
  console.log(req.body)
  res.status(200).end()
})
```

But this returns the error `Cannot POST //someValue`. How do I correctly change the post url?

Answer (score 0):

Your request is adding a '/'char before the /someValue route.
You can use a middleware to sanitize the path before searching for the routes, or you can review your GAS code to remove the duplicated '/'